# Has anyone encountered hundreds of errors while compiling cmsis_armcc.h with complier v6?

Tags: stm32, keil

Hundreds of errors while compiling cmsis_armcc.h.
Most of them are
expected identifier or '('
or
unknown register name.
The cmsis_armcc.h file is up-to-date.

[expected identifier or '('](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tC26f.png)

[unknown register name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFs0p.png)

Comment: usually you get a million errors because of one specific error in your code (try to find the earliest 3 error messages, they should hint). And then the compiler just keeps parsing stuff with one bracket off and runs into errors and errors and errors. It looks like you may have forgotten to include some file (unknown register name), and maybe lost a bracket in your code somewhere. Your question is very unspecific, you could at least describe what you're doing and what changes you did to your code since it worked ok.

Comment: Alternatively, if it never worked, then you set it up incorrectly in your IDE. There should be some material available in the internet about how to do it (specifically this IDE and this compiler)

Comment: can you elaborate? also, you do not compile h files....

Comment: Solved. Should not define __CC_ARM while using compiler v6.